# Enumerate over 2 array's of same shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, enumerate

I have to perform a lot of different types of functions over multi-dimensional data (sometimes 4D, sometimes 3D). I found an efficient way to enumerate over these arrays using `np.ndenumerate`. This is however limited to 1 array to iterate over at a time.

To solve the problem of having multiple types of dimensions but still being able to use the same function to modify / update / use etc. the data inside those arrays I would like to be able to do transform my current static version:

```
# Random data
array1 = np.random.rand(5, 7, 50, 40)
array2 = np.random.rand(5, 7, 50, 40)
result = np.zeros(array1.shape)
for (a, b, c, d), array1Data in np.ndenumerate(array1):
    array2Data = array2[a][b][c][d]
    result[a][b][c][d] = np.sqrt(array1Data**2 + array2Data**2)

print(result)
```

into something like:

```
# Random data
array1 = np.random.rand(5, 7, 50, 40)
array2 = np.random.rand(5, 7, 50, 40)
result = np.zeros(array1.shape)
for indexes, array1Data, array2Data in np.ndenumerate(array1, array2):
    result[indexes] = np.sqrt(array1Data**2 + array2Data**2)

print(result)
```

Comment: Can't you just write `result = np.sqrt(array1**2 + array2**2)`?

Comment: Yes for the example you can but whenever there are indexes to skip or if else statements inside I prefer to avoid a 1 liner and make the code in more natural language so I still know what I did when I look over it a month later.

Answer (score 1):

As if typing the question acts as a rubber ducky, I solved it by using a helper function `enumerate2D`:

```
def enumerate2D(array1, array2):
    assert array1.shape == array2.shape, "Error - dimensions."
    for indexes, data in np.ndenumerate(array1):
        yield indexes, data, array2[indexes]
```

Which can be used exactly as I described above:

```
for indexes, data1, data2 in enumerate2D(array1, array2):
    result[indexes] = np.sqrt(data1**2 + data2**2)
```